# How do i enable Text field on activating the switch?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have an array on which i am looping to get 4 switches, i have a text field that is disabled and i want to enable it when i enable one of the switch and ofcourse the field should disable when i turn off the switch.  How do i achieve it?

Below is my Template and my Script that i am using.

```
 <div class="body-2">Hello There:</div>
      <div class="caption">This is Some Text</div>
      <v-switch :v-model="`${project.model}`" v-for="project in projects" 
      :key="project.status" 
      :label="`${project.status}`"></v-switch>
      <v-text-field :disabled="!enabled" label="This is My Label"</v-text-field>




export default{
    data(){
    return{
    enabled:false,
    projects:
    [ {status:"Text1", model:"enabled1"},
    {status:"Text2",model:"enabled2"},
    {status:"Text3",model:"enabled3"},
    {status:"Text4",model:"enabled4"}
       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with vuetify, but if you could simply use the `.model` property of each project object as the switch `v-model`, you could make `.enabled` a computed property instead of a data property:

```
computed: {
    enabled() {
        return this.projects.some(project => project.model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to enable the input if one switch is on but have it disabled if all four switches are off.

The disabled property can be bound to a computed property that returns false if one of the switches is on and true if all four switches are off.

If this is a custom component, another options is to emit a custom event from the child component (v-switch) that emits whether the switch is on or off, and then call a method that sets a Boolean that you bind to :disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is a rather good idea. I'll  work on this and i'll let you know what comes out of it.

Comment: Yeah if all of them are off, it should be off and as soon as even one is turned on, the text field gets enabled.

Comment: If this is Vuetify, your v-model should be a true or false, and you can map it and count the number of false’s in the resulting array.

Comment: How would i map it in an array if my v-model is already set to true or false? to count that in an array i'm gonna have to v-model it to an empty array.

Comment: You’re v-model is set to a object in your data property. projects.model. So myArray = projects.map(e => e.model);

Comment: Okay so i got it to work but i used the value property of switch kinda like checkbox.
So this is how i got it to work:-
        <v-switch v-model="enabled" v-for="project in projects" 
       :key="project.status" :label="`${project.status}`" :value="project.status"</v-switch>
     <v-text-field :disabled="!enabled.length" label="Enter AutoBytel Dealer Id"> 
   </v-text-field>
And set the enabled value to an empty array.